# jQuery SessionStorage - Key not loading in current session

Tags: jquery, session

I have a jQuery/Phonegap app that uses a bunch of AJAX to load session variables from JSON web services. I'm trying to setup an environment where all session data is fresh on load and then is created as the functions are run. My problem is that one of the keys isn't loading in the current session. If I don't clear the uid it will show up on future runs. For example, when I run thru the on.click function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#page_login_submit", function () {
  //Clear UID
  sessionStorage.removeItem('uid');
  console.log("Setting Token");
  setToken();
  console.log(sessionStorage.token);
  console.log("Testing Connection");
  testConnect();
  console.log("Done");
  console.log(sessionStorage.uid);
});
```

I get the token fine everytime but I don't get uid EVER unless I DON'T remove uid on start. Apparently the id is being removed after testConnect() even though the removeItem is run before that function. If I comment out removeItem('uid) it shows up on the second on the first console output.

**What is the proper way to handle the sessionStorage values?**